# How to increase the width and height of the Rich Text area field in Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, richtextarea

i have to increase the width and height of the Rich Text area field in Visualforce page. I have tried the following:

**Method 01:**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Notes" columns="4">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Special notes" for="tts_notes"/>
                    <apex:inputTextarea id="tts_notes" value="{!Territory__c.Special_notes__c}" cols="50" rows="30" richText="true"/><p/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Method 02:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Notes" columns="4">
        <apex:inputField value="{!Territory__c.Special_notes__c}" style="width: 1000px; height: 700px;"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I have tried with Cols & rows attribute also but there is no change.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: style should work if columns are 1.Can you try that and then if its 4 columns then we can observe the change

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110781/how-to-increase-the-width-and-height-of-the-rich-text-area-field-in-visual-force Please refer the link. The issue was resolved here.

Answer (score 2):

In your code instead of columns= "4" use "1" then no need to apply styles also

Answer (score 2):

Well its in the salesforce doc!
Have a look here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputTextarea.htm

**According to the doc**

"**rows**" :    "**Integer**" : The height of the text area, as expressed by the number of rows that can display at a time.

"**cols**": "**Integer**" : The width of the field, as expressed by the number of characters that can display in a single row at a time.

And additionally make sure there is enough room for it to expand. So when you are marking pageBlocksection as columns="4" you are essentially dividing it into 4 parts and each component you add there takes a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got the answer on this question. For anyone who visits the page.

[How to increase the width and height of the Rich Text area field in Visual force Page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110781/how-to-increase-the-width-and-height-of-the-rich-text-area-field-in-visual-force?rq=1)