# How to increase the width and height of the Rich Text area field in Visual force Page?

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I know this question has been asked earlier. but did not see proper responses so asking again.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Preview Pane" columns="1">
    <apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="EmailBody" label="EmailBody"  
         cols="1" ondblclick="false" disabled="false" 
         value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I have tried to set the column value for the pageblock section. As well as for the inputtextarea. Still the column width dose not span the entire page.

[image: The lines on the side denote the end of page]

```
<apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="EmailBody" label="EmailBody" cols="1" 
   ondblclick="false" disabled="false" value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}" 
   style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="EmailBody" label="EmailBody"  cols="1" ondblclick="false" disabled="false" value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}" style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>` ? is it working ?

Comment: Yes tried that, did not help. Also tried to make the width as 100%

Comment: Here is a link to the earlier question raised :http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21371/how-to-increase-the-width-and-height-of-the-rich-text-area-field-in-visualforce

Comment: Still looks the same

Comment: have you tried rows attribute?

Comment: @chinmaybhusari ... Yes use row attribute.... `<apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="EmailBody" label="EmailBody" cols="1" ondblclick="false" disabled="false" value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}" row="100"/>`

Comment: Checked now, rows is working correctly. I needed the width to span the entire page

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputSecret.htm

Comment: Use the link to refer all tags & usage of attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Use the inputtextarea outside of pageblocksection. It should only be nested by pageblock.**

**Use row and cols attribute** of `apex:inputTextarea`

```
<apex:inputTextarea richtext="true" id="EmailBody" label="EmailBody" cols="1" 
      ondblclick="false" disabled="false" 
      value="{!emailTemplateSelected.htmlValue}" row="100"/>
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputTextarea.htm

**According to the doc**

"**rows**" :    "**Integer**" : The height of the text area, as expressed by the number of rows that can display at a time.

"**cols**": "**Integer**" : The width of the field, as expressed by the number of characters that can display in a single row at a time.

And additionally make sure there is enough room for it to expand. So when you are marking pageBlocksection as columns="4" you are essentially dividing it into 4 parts and each component you add there takes a part of it.

[image]

Comment: Ratan i need the width of the input rich text area to span the entire page. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: @chinmaybhusari change `col` use or cols="100"  or something based on your required

Comment: @chinmaybhusari some time cols will not because of its parent element will not give proper space.

Comment: but the parent in this case has been set to column width "1" . So where is it going wrong ?

Comment: @chinmaybhusari may be issue with something. I suggest for testing use this apex:inputTextArea out side of you elements. Use below pageblock or apex:form

Comment: @chinmaybhusari found the issue... Just remove your `apex:pageBlockSection` and use apex:inputTextArea out side of that pageblock section.... cols will work

Comment: Yes that worked !!! Awesome. Thanks a lot for your help.I cannot thank you enough.